# linux c get system date format yyyymmdd

Tags: c, linux, time

I want ask some questions
1) I want get string yyyymmdd of system date using linux c how should I do it ? And I want use this string do some arithmetic, like I have "20160317" I want do
 20160317 - 90 get a new date,pls help

2)

```
   int n;
   int m;
   n = (m%10 = 0)?(m/10):(m/10+1);
```

is there some cleaner way to do this? like if m = 11 n will get 2, m = 10 n will get 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert from a string to a time structure using [strptime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) (Linux only). This will set the time on a tm struct that is passed to it.

You can then use the [ctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/) library. It will let you use `difftime` which will give you get the difference between two times.

Comment: I get the time string from user input, and latest 90 days is legal

Comment: Ok, I've updated with how to convert from string to time.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

If this answered your question, can you click the tick next to the answer to mark it as accepted.

Comment: but i aslo want to wait some alldone program with code...if no one answer i will accept you

Answer (score 1):

Consider c standard function. [strftime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime)

```
#include <time.h>

char datename[32];
struct tm* to;
time_t t;
t = time(NULL);
to = localtime(&t);
strftime(datename, sizeof(datename), "%Y%m%d", to);
```

if you want date of 90 days before. just

```
t -= 90 * 24 * 3600;
```

Comment: `strftime` takes a time struct and formats a string accordingly. Hhdzhu already has the time as a string.